# Do all user mode processes started in Windows go through CreateProcess?

Tags: winapi

Is there any bottleneck above the physical the cpu and HAL? Or are there multiple ways a process could start under Windows XP, Vista, or 7, that don't invovle CreateProcess at some point?

Comment: Of course everything goes through the cpu at some point, but in Windows is there a single function responsible for spawning all user mode processes?

Comment: What is the practical programming problem you're having?

Comment: Certainly all user mode processes are created in a uniform fashion in the kernel, through some usermode API. I'm not really sure how else it could be done. You mention "bottleneck" so I assume you're trying to start processes faster? This isn't really an answerable question.

Comment: Building an Anti-Executable driver, just planning, wondering if controlling createprocess would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the comment on your question:

> Building an Anti-Executable driver, just planning, wondering if controlling createprocess would be enough.

No it wouldn't be enough if security is your concern. There is `NtCreateProcess` below that one for example. And those aren't the only ones.

The best way provided by the system is a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx). In fact the WDK comes with samples that require only a moderate amount of change to do what you're asking. Since you asked about XP you can use a minifilter if you can get away with support for XP SP1 and later.

[`PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559957.aspx) and [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951.aspx) are unfortunately only notifications. So they don't allow to do anything about the event that they notify about. And you *really* shouldn't attempt to work around this.

In the old times I have seen some clever implementations using SSDT hooks on `ZwCreateSection` that would exchange the returned handle with one to an executable that shows an error message. Since the executable itself sees the original command line, it can then show a nice error message informing the user that the command has been banned for reasons xyz. However, with Vista and later and even on XP and 2003 64bit (x64), it's going to be harder to write the SSDT hooks. Not to mention that everyone would frown upon it, that it requires quite extensive experience to get it right (and even then it often has flaws that can cause havoc) and that you can forget any certifications you may be aspiring for in the Windows Logo process.

Conclusion: use a file system filter driver to deny access to unwanted executables. With a minifilter the learning curve will be moderate, with a legacy filter I'll recommend you take a few courses first and then start your first attempts.

Comment: Thanks, I found this article, http://w.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=214954, on using PreAcquireForSectionSynchronization, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Even that isn't good enough. Somebody can create a process that passes your filter, then replaces every byte of the process with the executable you want to block.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: how would you pull this off from UM? I agree that this should be *possible*, but it wouldn't really matter. As soon as malevolent code gets to run in the TCB (and that even includes UM parts) all bets are off. It simply becomes an arms race from that point on as the KM rootkits prove. What else am I missing?

Comment: My point is that the goal of "allow the user to run any program except X" is not achievable because the user can create a program Y that morphs into program X at runtime. If you say that that "doesn't really matter", then you can just use existing mechanisms built into Windows (like SAFER policy) rather than trying to create your own.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: fair point. SAFER policy was introduced only with 7, though, no? A mini-FSFD would work before that. Besides, the vetting of what gets opened should obviously not be limited by *file name* but rather by contents, including dependencies. In this case it should be a lot harder to smuggle unwanted stuff in, the way you describe it. Add ACLs into the mix and it should be relatively solid. Also when the MS folks presented the SAFER stuff in 7 beta there were some limitations that made it a bit unwieldy for admins (not fine-grained enough). Possible this was fixed meanwhile.

Comment: Harder but not impossible. The rogue payload can be encrypted to avoid detection. And as malware has demonstrated, only one person needs to do the hard thing; everybody else can just copy it.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, I would have to run a program that had a big enough security hole in it to allow foreign code to somehow use CreateProcess, right? Still, I plan to solve this problem using ObRegisterCallbacks with OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE and OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_DUPLICATE and remove access to PROCESS_VM_OPERATION for all protected processes.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, It seems [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine*Ex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does allow the canceling of the creation. You may wish to update the answer.

Comment: @Motes: didn't you write XP onwards? The mini-FSFD would work from XP and later or even Windows 2000 SP4 + SRP + patch and later.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, thanks, I didn't take into account the Ex version was only for Vista and above. I will use PreAcquireForSectionSynchronization instead.

Comment: @Motes Somebody can write a Program Y that explicitly contains the security hole, specifically to circumvent your attempt to block Program X. E.g. "EncryptedProgramX.exe" that passes your filter, and then once executed decrypts in memory and executes a copy of Program X.

Comment: @Motes If you are blocking all unrecognized programs, then you have a better chance of succeeding, although RunDll32 is a common way of placing malicious code outside an EXE.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through a quick disassembly of `CreateProcess`, it appears that the two *main* things it does are:

- Call `NtCreateUserProcess` (this is syscall 0xAA) to actually create the process structures in the kernel ([PEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block), etc.)
- Start the new process with a call to `NtResumeThread` (syscall 0x4F).

The [Windows Internals books](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) certainly detail this process very well.

I'm not sure if there are designated hooks in the kernel which would allow you to create your anti-executable driver.  It used to be that you could hook the ["System Service Dispatch Table"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Service_Dispatch_Table) to change how these system calls behaved. But now, technologies like [PatchGuard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection) prevent a driver from doing this (and allowing the system to run).

Comment: Just so you know, syscall numbers on windows aren't stable an can change with any windows update patch.